# array_push adds another empty array after adding my array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I was working on a way to populate an empty array.

I have this code:

```
$array = array();
$month = 'enero';
array_push($array, $array[$month] = array('01'));
array_push($array['enero'], '02');
print_r($array);
```

This returns:

```
Array
(
    [enero] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01
            [1] => 02
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01
        )

)
```

The array `[0]` appears from nowhere and I don't know what to do. I have tried

```
array_push($array['enero'], '02');
```

But it does not work. How can I get the expected result:

```
Array 
( 
    [enero] => Array 
        ( 
            [0] => 01 
            [1] => 02 
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, avoid `array_push` and just use `[]` notation. It has the advantage of automatically creating sub-arrays that don't exist (so no need to use `$array[$month] = array();`):

```
$array = array();
$month = 'enero';
$array[$month][] = '01';
$array[$month][] = '02';
print_r($array);
```

If you want to use `array_push`, you need to create the `enero` element first before attempting to push into it:

```
$array = array();
$month = 'enero';
$array[$month] = array();
array_push($array[$month], '01');
array_push($array[$month], '02');
print_r($array);
```

Output (for both pieces of code):

```
Array
(
    [enero] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01
            [1] => 02
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kZJkn)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you use `array()` instead of `[]`?

Comment: @ggorlen just personal preference. I find the `[` and `]` around array values can get lost in a page of code but `array(...)` always sticks out.

Comment: Oh.... I thought this way would not work because the $array variable would be re-asigned in each loop itinerance. thank you.